# How can I return an element of a MongoDB array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

If I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "favoriteFoods": [{"name": "Cheeseburgers"}, {"name": "Broccoli"}]
}
```

And I want to create a search expression in NodeJS to return just the element's of `favoriteFood` `name` matches `req.body.term`, how could I implement this? I have tried the code below, but this returns an entire document, which I don't want because I have to filter the array.

```
User.find({"favoriteFoods.title": {$regex: req.body.term, $options: "i"}})
        .then((food) => {
            res.status(200).send(food);
        })
```

Comment: Why are you matching with `favoriteFoods.title` while your sample documents are using `favoriteFoods.name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to match the values.

```
res.status(200).send(food.favoriteFoods
  .filter(food => food.title.match(new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i'))
);
```

You used `name` in the example JSON but `title` in the code, so make sure you're using whichever of those is actually correct

Also, allowing users to specify their own regular expressions could allow for [Regex DOS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) attacks, so be warned of that.

Comment: Having a DB why to filter using JS code? It is better to get values already filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at all the desired format result so here you have multiple ways to get that:

1. Using [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) into the projection stage:

```js
db.collection.find({},
{
  "favoriteFoods": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "name": {
        "$regex": "chee",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But be careful, `$elemMatch` only return one result. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EHsBwGxydbF).

2. Using `$filter` into an aggregation stage: This query will return an array called "food" only with objects that matches the regex.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "food": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$favoriteFoods",
          "cond": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$$this.name",
              "regex": "chee",
              "options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It will return more than one objecs if they match. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/So5pZODMQOR)

3. Using `$unwind` and `$match`: This query uses `$unwind` which is not the best step you want to use but it is very useful. Using it with `$match` and `$project` you can get the result into an object and not an array (keeping in mind that mongo result is always an array, but each object inside will have `food` property and will not be an array).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$favoriteFoods"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "favoriteFoods.name": {
        "$regex": "chee",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "food": "$favoriteFoods.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXQuE6F0_ef)

Comment: These are all nice solutions. Maybe we can also put the filter OP wanted in the `find` clause or an early `$match` stage so we only process the documents that matched the filter. :)